# DB fields are not properly mapped to java objects when using reactive postgres r2dbc

Tags: postgresql, spring-webflux, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc, r2dbc-postgresql

I have a Spring Boot application with reactive stack (WebFlux). I work with PostgreSQL database using r2dbc driver. DB contains 2 records with all values present, but when I query I get empty fields. Below you can see the service response.

```
[
    {
        "pkey": null,
        "description": null,
        "uid": null,
        "isActive": null
    },
    {
        "pkey": null,
        "description": null,
        "uid": null,
        "isActive": null
    }
]
```

Entity class:

```
import lombok.AllArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Immutable;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Column;
import org.springframework.data.relational.core.mapping.Table;

@Getter
@Setter
@Builder
@ToString
@Immutable
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "channel", schema = "myschema")
public class ChannelView {
    @Id
    @Column("pkey")
    private Integer pkey;

    @Column("description")
    private String description;

    @Column("uid")
    private String uid;

    @Column("is_active")
    private Boolean isActive;
}
```

Data received through reactive repo using its default generated findAll() method:

```
import com.myproject.dao.entity.ChannelView;
import org.springframework.data.r2dbc.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import org.springframework.data.repository.reactive.ReactiveCrudRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

@Repository
public interface ChannelViewRepository extends ReactiveCrudRepository<ChannelView, Integer> {
}
```

Note that channel is actually a view, not a table. Probably it's the problem. But in non-reactive approach it works right (jdbc driver).

Answer (score 0):

My mistake was in using @Immutable on entity class, I removed it and now it returns all the fields!